# Bootstrap navbar dropdown-menu doesn't work properly on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason I am having a few issues with my navbar, all of which appear to only happen on mobile.

The navbar itself stays open when navigating to another page (but only sometimes).

Sometimes the navbar won't event open, I have to reload the page to get it to work.

Sometimes links in the dropdown menu under "About" won't go where they're supposed to, they just go to "#". And other times "About" won't even drop down at all.

Here is my code:

```
<nav>
                <div id="top" class="row">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="resources/css/img/brand2.png" class="logo"></a>
                    <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
                        <li><a id="workout" href="theworkout.html">The Workout</a></li>
                        <li><a href="motivators.html">Trainers</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="thelevels.html">The Levels</a></li>
                                <li><a href="sixpunches.html">Learn the Moves</a></li>
                                <li><a href="philosophy.html">Philosophy</a></li>
                                <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                                <li><a href="press.html">Press</a></li>
                                <li><a href="privateevents.html">Private Events</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="buyclasses.html">Buy Classes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="accountButton">My Account</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="ion-navicon-round"></i></a>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

It's just very confusing because it doesn't happen all the time and also seems to happen randomly. I can't even pinpoint when it happens.

I also have this error in my console, but I'm not sure if it's related:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=#]:not([href=#])
    at Function.fa.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.fa [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:28)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
```

The jquery file is untouched by me and straight from google (again, not sure if this is even related to my issue):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using? Could this be related? https://forums.asp.net/t/2120709.aspx?Jquery+version+update+problem+navigation+dropdown+is+not+working

Comment: @Gerard I am using boostrap 3.3.7. Should I try changing to an older version? Do you have a suggested version?

Comment: I would go for version 3.2.1